# Saving X, Y coordinates of nodes

Tags: grass-gis, export, network, references, nodes

I have to manage a network, made by essentially the streets of a city which has to serve some buildings.

I used GRASS **v.clean** to clean the network and then **v.net.nodes** to make nodes and then I save the vector as a csv file to collect coordinates of nodes.

In this process I came upon a problem: saving the vector of nodes in this way I obtained a csv file with "x,y,cat" instead of simply "x,y", so as to have a third empty element for each line like this "20.34,30.34, ,".

How to have only X and Y coordinates without "cat"?

Comment: I think your two objectives represent two questions and as per the 2-minute [Tour], which every user of this site is expected to take to learn its protocols, there should be only one question asked per question.